# Newbie: Can anyone explain the behavior here when using map function with three arguments on a 3 element array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to JavaScript, got this error while exploring the map function in ES6

```
const numbers = [1,2,3];

const doubleNumArray = numbers.map((num1, num2, num3) => {
  return [num1 * 2, num2*3, num3*4];
});

console.log(numbers);
console.log(doubleNumArray);
```

which generates the output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[[2, 0, NaN], [4, 3, NaN], [6, 6, NaN]]
```

I'm confused about what happened inside doubleNumArray, why didn't it apply each multiplication to each element of the numbers array? Why did it generate a NaN in the last index, but not the others?

Comment: I suggest that you reread [the description of the `.map()` method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Second argument of map is the index of the array element.

Comment: `map` calls the function you give it on every element in the array... So, it calls that function _3_ times, instead of _once_ with 3 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Arr.map`, in the callback you will get 3 arguments:

1. Element
2. index of element in the array
3. Array itself

In your code,
you are multiplying `2` with the element ( `[1*2, 2*2, 3*3 ]`)
you are multiplying the `3` with it's index ( `[0*3, 1*3, 2*3 ]`)
you are multiplying array with the number ( because of which you are getting `NaN` )